# Google Polymer verbose selectors

Tags: polymer

Reading Polymer 1.0 documentation I see that the way to select an element inside of polymer element is to use following: `Polymer.dom(parent).querySelector(selector)`

Was curious if there is an abbreviated version of this call. Something closer to what jQuery has `$(selector)`

Comment: if you try to access from inside the Polymer element, this.$.id would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Polymer provides a `$$` method, documented here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding

Example:

```
this.$$('.my-classes')
```

Comment: Trying to figure out the difference between using `this.$$(slector)` and `Polymer.dom(parent).querySelector(selector)`  So, with `Polymer.dom()` you can specify any component in the DOM while `this.$$` refers to elements inside specific polymer element?

Comment: The specific code for `$$` is:
`$$: function(slctr) {
  return Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(slctr);
}`

Comment: So that would seem to restrict `this.$$` to the specific element, yes.